# conditions in Case statement

Tags: sql, case-expression

```
select min(measurement), part_desc
    (case len(measurement)
        when 6 then '0000' + part_desc
        else '000' + part_desc
        end)
from LeachingView
where DateTimeStamp > '2011-01-01' and measurement > 0
group by measurement, part_desc
```

That is suppposed to append 0000's to the front of another char, but it doesn't work, and i was wondering why and how to make it correct.

The error I get is this:

> 'part_desc' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't really need a CASE at all...

```
select
    min(measurement),
    RIGHT('0000000000' + part_desc, 10) AS part_desc
from...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(measurement), 
    case len(measurement)
        when 6 then '0000' + part_desc
        else '000' + part_desc
    end as part_desc
from LeachingView
where DateTimeStamp > '2011-01-01' 
    and measurement > 0                        
group by case len(measurement)
        when 6 then '0000' + part_desc
        else '000' + part_desc
    end
```

Comment: why not tell him why it was broken?  that seems like the important part.

Comment: that seems to have doubled the amount of 0's preappended

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
Select min(measurment),
       (case len(measurement)
         when 6 then '0000' + part_desc
         else '000' + part_desc
        end) AS "part_desc"
From LeachingView
Where...
```